# Why does this function extend uniquely? Plancherel and Hilbert Automorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider

> There exists a unique Hilbert space automorphism $F: \mathcal{L}^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^2$ such that
> $$
> F([f])=\left[(2 \pi)^{-d / 2} \hat{f}\right]
> $$
> whenever $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$.

> Proof. We define $F_0: \mathcal{L}^1 \cap \mathcal{L}^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^2$ by
> $$
> F_0([f])=\left[(2 \pi)^{-d / 2} \hat{f}\right]
> $$ By the Plancherel identity we know $F_0$ preserves the $L^2$ norm, i.e.
> $$
> \left\|F_0([f])\right\|_2=\|[f]\|_2
> $$
> Also, we know that $\mathcal{L}^1 \cap \mathcal{L}^2$ is dense in $\mathcal{L}^2$, since even the continuous functions with compact support are dense. So we know $F_0$ extends uniquely to an isometry $F: \mathcal{L}^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^2$. (the proof then continues to show injectivity and surjectivity.

**Issues:** I am struggling to see how one expands it. On a different notes on the same course (from a previous year), the author claims that this is by "enforcing continuity". This makes no sense - nowhere do we require $F$ to be continuous. The definition of Hilbert space automorphism that was given to me is is that it is a linear bijection between two hilbert spaces.

I thought I could argue by linearity but this will end up reducing to continuity which need not be true as in infinite dimensions we know that linear maps need not be continuous.

**Question:** How does one show the uniqueness of the extension/ where does continuity come from?

**Context**: This comes from a course lectured on notes [http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/pm.pdf](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejames/Lectures/pm.pdf). See page 41.

Comment: I’m not sure what difference you make between $\mathcal{L}$ and $L$ (the latter is made if genuine functions, the latter of functions up to equality ae)? Anyway, you define $F(f)$ as the limit of $F_0(f_n)$ for any sequence $f_n \in L^1 \cap L^2$ converging to $f$. It’s a common construction in functional analysis, and I encourage you to work out the details (definition, linearity, continuity) if they do not seem clear to you.

Comment: Hi @Aphelli. Thank you for the comment. I think there is an issue with one of my definitions here (or I am missing something very obvious). From what I see I need not have $F$ continuous and therefore I need not have the uniqueness of limits. Sure I see that I can construct a continuous function and I know that it will be unique amongsts the continuous functions, however, how do I know that there is not one discontinuous function? Does linearity gurantee everything? This seems not obvious to me.